# Remove character from code with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove an em dash from a pre made piece of code. However, it is imbedded in the tree and I cannot seem to access it:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/bhAtn/1/)

HTML:

```
  <span class="price">           
        <span class="price">
            <span class="amount">£8.75</span>
            – // I need this!
            <span class="amount">£19.20</span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

JS:

```
$('span.price').each(function(){
    $(this)
        .find('.amount')
        .next()
        .remove()

    var c = $(this);
    var t  = c.text();
    var b = t.replace('—', '@'); // but if i use ('£', '@') it replaces the pound sign
    c.text(b);

});
```

Would anyone know why the above does not find and replace the '—' dash?

Comment: Why it doesn't work? It *does*, though I replaced the `-` character you had in your `replace()` with this one `–`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bhAtn/8/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [.filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to find all text nodes whose content is `-` and remove it:

```
$(".price").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.textContent) === "–";
}).remove();
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FXxa8/1/)

edit: Changed to use jQuery's trim rather than ES5 as this will work on < IE9

Comment: Much more thorough than my suggestion.  I always want to go down this route but can never remember it.  Gonna bookmark it this time ;)

Comment: @Archer I always revert to looking for text nodes because my regex sucks and it's easier to do a direct compare

Comment: This is much easier to read than using regex.  Also, I wish my regex sucked.  I don't even qualify for that level.  My idea of using regex starts with typing google.com :p

Answer (score 2):

Funny thing :)
I copied "-" from html part of jsfiddle into your code

```
var b = t.replace("–", '@');
```

and now replace does work. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/bhAtn/7/

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/bhAtn/5/)</kbd>

Try below code, it will work

```
$('span.price').each(function(){
    $(this)
        .find('.amount')
        .next()
        .remove()
    .end();
    var c = $(this);
    var t  = c.text();
    var b = t.replace(/–/g, ' ');
    c.text(b);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simplistic and is for your specific purpose, but does the trick...

```
$('span.price > span.price').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace("–", ""));
});
```

**[<kbd>jsfiddle example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/bhAtn/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element content filter only the textnodes and remove them.

Code:

```
$('span.price').each(function () {
    $(this)
        .contents()
        .filter(function () {
        return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
    }).remove();

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/fSMKL/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
$('span.price span.amount').each(function(){
    if (this.nextSibling) {
        this.nextSibling.nodeValue = this.nextSibling.nodeValue.replace(/—/g,'');
    }
})
```